# Check my Python code and suggest me the edits required

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I've Just started learning python. I am trying to learn making a program which asks the user their name and place they want to visit. And display result at end of survey.But if a user opts to pass the survey to other user, the Poll result displayed is only consisting the name and place of the last user who answered these question.What can I do such that the program displays result of all users entered in the poll.  (code is self explanatory)

```
print("Hello world")
qstn_1="What is your name?\t"
qstn_2="Where would you like to GO for vacation?\t"
polling_active=True
while polling_active:
 name=input(qstn_1)
 place=input(qstn_2)
 other=input("Would you like other person to answer these survey questions ?\t\n")
 polling_active=False
 if other=='yes':
      polling_active=True
 else:
    polling_active=False 
      
    
print("\n\n\t\t\tPOLLING RESULTS\n")
print("\n\n\t" + name.title() + " would like to go to " + place + " for a vacation!\n")
```

Comment: You should store each result in a list and then display the whole content of the list. Your code is assigning `name` and `place` every time. Also fix your indent because it's hardly readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few fixes:

- Added list, and need to unpack the list in the end.

```
print("Hello world")
qstn_1="What is your name?\t"
qstn_2="Where would you like to GO for vacation?\t"
polling_active=True
name_lst = []
place_lst = []
while polling_active:
    name_lst.append(input(qstn_1))
    place_lst.append(input(qstn_2))
    other=input("Would you like other person to answer these survey questions ?\t\n")
    polling_active=False
    if other=='yes':
        polling_active=True

      
    
print("\n\n\t\t\tPOLLING RESULTS\n")
for i_name, i_place in zip(name_lst, place_lst):
    print("\n\n\t" + i_name.title() + " would like to go to " + i_place + " for a vacation!\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0
names = []
places = []
while True:
    choice = input("Type N to take survey, type Y to pass it other user :")
    if choice == 'Y' and count==0:
        print("No one has taken this survey")
        break


    elif choice == 'N':
        name = input("What is your name :")
        place = input("Where would you like to visit :")
        names.append(name)
        places.append(place)
        count += 1    

    elif choice == 'Y':
        print("The last user was", names[-1], "and", names[-1], "wanted to visit", places[-1])
        break

print("\n\n\t\t POLLING RESULTS\n")
for name, place in zip(names, places):
    print(name, "wanted to visit", place,"\n")
```